# Python numpy sampling a 2D array for n rows

Tags: python, numpy, sample

I have a numpy array as follows, I want to take a random sample of `n` rows.

```
             ([[996.924, 265.879, 191.655],
             [996.924, 265.874, 191.655],
             [996.925, 265.884, 191.655],
             [997.294, 265.621, 192.224],
             [997.294, 265.643, 192.225],
             [997.304, 265.652, 192.223]], dtype=float32)
```

I've tried:

```
rows_id = random.sample(range(0,arr.shape[1]-1), 1)
row = arr[rows_id, :]
```

But this 9ndex mask only returns a single row, I want to return `n` rows as an numpy array (without duplication).

Comment: Did you check if range(0,arr.shape[1]-1) returned what you expected? And rows_id?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code I posted, it looks like the mask array is 0 or 1, so that will not work, probably needs a `arr.size`  in there somewhere. Or is this over complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three key issues: `arr.shape[1]` returns the number of columns, while you want the number of rows--`arr.shape[0]`. Second, the second parameter to range is exclusive, so you don't really need the -1. Third, your last parameter to `random.sample` is the number of rows, which you set to 1.

A better way to do what you're trying might be [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try where `x` is your original array:

```
n = 2  #number of rows
idx = np.random.choice(len(x), n, replace = False)
result = np.array([x[i] for i in idx])
```